# How to create EventHandler for dynamically created buttons (for each one) C# VS2010

Tags: c#, jquery, button, event-handling

So, I have a form in which all buttons and textboxes and labes are dynamically generated

Code:

```
private void LoadElements()
            {
                int Y = 30;
                int j = 0;
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand populate = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", con);
                OleDbDataReader reader = populate.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    b = new Button();
                    b.Text = "Delete";
                    b.Name = reader["Username"].ToString();
                    b.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                    b.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    b.Location = new Point(240, Y);
                    b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    LB.Add(b);
                    tb1 = new TextBox();
                    tb1.Location = new Point(10, Y);
                    TB1.Add(tb1);
                    tb1.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
                    tb2 = new TextBox();
                    tb2.Location = new Point(120, Y);
                    tb2.Text = reader["Password"].ToString();
                    TB2.Add(tb2);
                    Y += 30;
                    j++;
                }

                foreach (Button BTN in LB) // <- this is a globaly declared List<Button>
                {
                    this.Controls.Add(BTN);
                    BTN.Click += new EventHandler(BTN_Click);
                }
                foreach (TextBox text1 in TB1)  // <= -||- List<TextBox>
                { this.Controls.Add(text1); }
                foreach (TextBox text2 in TB2)  // -||-
                { this.Controls.Add(text2); }

              // MORE CODE UNDER
      }
```

As you may or may not have noticed, the whole form is a "superadmin" type of form, all users and passwords are loaded from database onto it. I want to be able to have a reference to the created buttons, when a Delete button is clicked I want the program to go into the database and search "WHERE [Username] LIKE" + button.Name + ""(because the button name is the actually Username); My code creates elements dynamically like this: [Name] [Password] [Delete] in the form of [textbox1] [textbox2] [button]. Problem is whenever I click any of the buttons it only takes reference to the last one created, how could I make the event handler so that it can see every button's respective .name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivotal code is in the event handling procedure - you did not show that. Look at the object sender parameter, and use it accordingly!

```
void BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if (b!=null)
    {
        //that's your button, with the properties created in the loop.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your looking for this code.

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
```

Add it into your button creation...

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                b = new Button();
                b.Text = "Delete";
                b.Name = reader["Username"].ToString();
                b.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                b.Location = new Point(240, Y);
                b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                ***b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);***
                LB.Add(b);
            }
```

Comment: Yes, and with that, in the button click event handler I get a reference to the LAST added button (for example if I have button.names: John, Smith, Obama, If i click ANY of the buttons, my button.name will always be Obama, and it will delete Obama when I click any of the buttons (John or Smith).